# Flutter Web on Chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web

I've been trying to run my Flutter Web's project on Chrome but it keeps starting it on Chrome's guest mode feature (though I've disabled guest mode as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155127/can-i-disable-chrome-browsers-guest-mode)).

I've also tried running the project using `flutter run -d web-server` but the web page screen is empty without anything printed in console.

Is there anyway to run project on chrome default tabs?

I have also checked this issue but didn't help:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43809

Answer (score 1):

To solve, you have to set a webport because if we not set the port, flutter will always create a random port every run. So:

```
--web-port 5000
```

Then, open **flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart**

change this line (find it with *ctrl+f*)

```
final Directory userDataDir = _fileSystem.systemTempDirectory
      .createTempSync('flutter_tools_chrome_device.');
```

to

```
final Directory userDataDir = _fileSystem.currentDirectory.childDirectory('.dart_tool')
        .childDirectory('chrome-device');
```

then comment out this line (find it with *ctrl+f*, even though it should be just below the previous line)

```
// if (cacheDir != null) {
//   //Seed data dir with previous state.
//   _restoreUserSessionInformation(cacheDir, userDataDir);
// }
```

**Last step**,  go to *flutter/bin/cache* and delete the *flutter_tools.stamp* to force flutter tool build again file.
Finally run the app again, once or twice.

Credits: https://quango2304.medium.com/keep-flutter-web-storage-after-close-and-run-again-when-developing-7cb2118cbbb3

Answer (score 0):

After you run `flutter build web`, `cd` into `/build/web` directory of your Flutter project and run `python -m http.server 8000`. You can then open a normal chrome tab and visit "0.0.0.0:8000" where your site should be running. See more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release)